# How do you use jDeskew in Tess4j?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Documentation: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-2.0/

It is the packages > com.recognition.software.jdeskew.

I see that it calculates the skew, but **how are you suppose to use this in order to make an image more readable by tesseract** and improve the percentage of text correctly read? When I do this in code it just returns a number as you can see in documentation. The code I use below for what I am talking about. Also an image of what I am trying to correct.

```
ImageDeskew id = new ImageDeskew(img);
double angle = id.getSkewAngle();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps determine the angle that you will use to rotate an image that has been taken at an oblique angle. It does not help fix the page curl problem that you have. You probably would need a tool such as Scan Tailor or Book Scan Wizard.

Comment: You know leptonica can do this right? I just can't figure out how to get that thing to work with java. :( - Also, I posted a question in your source forge hoping you might get the idea to make it for me. I would also accept being pointed in the direction of how to make a wrapper. :P

Comment: Leptonica has many methods that certainly can help achieve this kind of image clean-ups. For a Leptonica JNA wrapper, search for "lept4j" on sourceforge or github.